# Use eclipse compare tool built-in in plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I'm trying to develop a plugin in Java for Eclipse. For this, I want to use the built-in tool used for comparing files.
I found some help in eclipse wiki (https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_a_compare_editor%3F) but it seems not enougth for a developpement since there are lot of empties in explanation.

I also found [this](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcompare%2Fpackage-summary.html) but there is no implementation or use sample to understand how it's work.

What I want is to show the compare tool view inside a plugin to manage some merges in a list of files.
I'm currently work on Neon.1 Release (4.6.1) of Eclipse on Windows 7 with Java 1.6.

Any kind of help will be apreciate.

Thanks.

Comment: The section 'Compare support' in the 'Platform Plug-in Developer Guide' in the Eclipse Help contains more information. But this is a very complex area and far too broad for a Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: Thank you @greg-449, I keep looking for a solution. If I find new clues, I put it here.

Comment: Eclipse Neon (4.6) is pretty old. You are 8 releases behind. Please upgrade to avoid facing already fixed bugs.